# How to allow softkeaybord cover only defined views?

Tags: android-layout, android-softkeyboard

My layout has the following structure:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

             ....

        </ScrollView>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logotyp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When softkeyboard appears, ImageView is moved up and ScrollView is resized. I want to make the ImagView was obscured by softkeyboard and ScrollView was still resized. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to monitor for [height change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264518/show-hidden-soft-keyboard-event-in-android) and then set the `ImageView` visibility to `View.GONE` when things get smaller.